# With jQuery and I need help getting individual table row titles attributes from an xml file

Tags: jquery, xml, tablesorter

I'm usig tablesorter jQuery to parse this xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<CATALOG>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Title 01</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Artist 01</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>Country 01</COUNTRY>
    <PRICE>10.00</PRICE>
    <YEAR>2010</YEAR>
    <INFO>Tooltip Info 01</INFO>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Title 02</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Artist 02</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>Country 02</COUNTRY>
    <PRICE>9.00</PRICE>
    <YEAR>2009</YEAR>
    <INFO>Tooltip Info 02</INFO>
  </CD>
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Title 03</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Artist 03</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>Country 03/COUNTRY>
    <PRICE>8.00</PRICE>
    <YEAR>2008</YEAR>
    <INFO>Tooltip Info 03</INFO>
  </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

and with this code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "file.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml){                 
       $(xml).find("CD").each(function(){                                             
          $("#tablebody").append('<tr><td>'
            + $(this).find("TITLE").text() 
            + '</td><td>'+ $(this).find("ARTIST").text() 
            + '</td><td>'+ $(this).find("COUNTRY").text() 
            + '</td><td>'+ $(this).find("PRICE").text() 
            + '</td><td>'+ $(this).find("YEAR").text() 
            + '</td></tr>');                        
          });
       }
  });
});
</script>
```

I'm new at javascript and have been trying with no luck for a couple of hrs to get the text from the INFO/INFO tags in the xml file to show as title attributes for each table row. The reason for that is that I need to have individual popup tooltips on mouse-over each table row.
Many Thanks in advance for any kind of help or suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

I would do it slightly differently to eliminate some repetitive code:

```
var cells = ["TITLE", "ARTIST", "COUNTRY", "PRICE", "YEAR"];

...

success: function(xml) {
  $(xml).find("CD").each(function() {
    var title = $(this).children("INFO").text();
    var row = $("<tr>").attr("title", title).appendTo("#tablebody");
    for (var i=0; i<cells.length; i++) {
      var text = $(this).children(cells[i]).text();
      $("<td>").text(text).appendTo(row);
    }
  }
```

`cells` is just an array of the child elements you want to create table cells from. Creating markup the way you do can get slow. The above method is much faster. The `title` attribute on the row is what produces the tool tip.

Comment: Doesn't using this method with numerous appends (e.g. creating a large table) significantly decrease performance? (ref: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#tablebody").append("<tr title='" + $(this).find("INFO").text() + "'><td>"
            + $(this).find("TITLE").text() 
            + '</td><td>'+ $(this).find("ARTIST").text() 
            + '</td><td>'+ $(this).find("COUNTRY").text() 
            + '</td><td>'+ $(this).find("PRICE").text() 
            + '</td><td>'+ $(this).find("YEAR").text() 
            + '</td></tr>');                        
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

For better performance (if the output is very large), use this function:

```
success: function(xml){
  var content = '';
  $(xml).find("CD").each(function(){
    content += '<tr title="' + $(this).find("INFO").text() + '"><td>' +
    $(this).find("TITLE").text() + '</td><td>' +
    $(this).find("ARTIST").text() + '</td><td>' +
    $(this).find("COUNTRY").text() + '</td><td>' +
    $(this).find("PRICE").text() + '</td><td>' + 
    $(this).find("YEAR").text() + '</td></tr>';
  });
  $("#tablebody").append(content);
}
```

From [this article](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/03/43439-reasons-to-use-append-correctly), the best performance would be to not use the `.each` function and use arrays and such, but I didn't use that method as it is a bit harder to read and understand especially to someone new to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

biterscript to get all TITLES (or tag values of one tag type).

```
# Script XMLTags.txt
var str document, xml, tagtype, tagvalue, searchRE
set $searchRE = "^<"+$tagtype+"&</"+$tagtype+"^"
cat $document > $xml
while ( { sen -r -c $searchRE $xml } > 0 )
do
    stex -r -c $searchRE $xml > $tagvalue
    stex "^>^]" $tagvalue > null
    stex "]^<^" $tagvalue
done
```

Call the script like this from calling script.

```
script XMLTags.txt document("http://www.xxx.yyy/file.xml") tagtype("TITLE")
```

Will get all titles.

```
script XMLTags.txt document("http://www.xxx.yyy/file.xml") tagtype("ARTIST")
```

Will get all artists.

etc.